# jquery autocomplete for multi column not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, json, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Currently working on jQuery auto complete (multi column) where the value is coming from json with my current code I am getting the below error coming from jQuery UI.

Here is my JSON data I have validate this json with this [json](http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer)

```
{
    "school": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "schoolname_heading" : "Emirates College of Technology- UAE",
            "description": "COL000001"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "schoolname_heading" : "Al Khawarizmi International College- UAE",
            "description": "COL000002"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "schoolname_heading" : "Syscoms College",
            "description": "COL000003"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "schoolname_heading": "Other 1",
            "description": "Other"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my jquery code in this [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/7v9bfLr0/3/)

With the current code i am getting the header as the value.

Any suggestion guys.

Thanks in advance

Comment: autocomplete requires label/value pair in your response data by default. Your JSON data is 'schoolname_heading' and 'description'. I'm not sure if that error is caused by this. Try to use $.map to map your response to 'label' and 'value' field in your ajax success function.

Comment: Iam new to ajax and json can you please help me